# Trabajar con el valor numérico de la hora en milisegundos

Tags: android-studio, firebase

lo que estoy tratando de buscar es como convertir una fecha similar `26/12/2017 1:56:07 GMT- 0500 (-05)` a un valor entero ejemplo `1514271367000` en `Android Studio.` 
Quiero usar ese formato de fecha para usarlo en firebase y hacer una consulta por rango de fechas.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 int i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
```

Donde `new Date().getTime()` si no es la fecha actual que estas utilizando debe estar en formato date.

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puede configurar la hora del servidor usando "ServerValue.TIMESTAMP". Cuando se envía a la base de datos firebase, se convertirá a un tiempo como este 1469554720.

Por ejemplo

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String key = ref.push().getKey(); // this will create a new unique key
Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("name", "shesh");
value.put("address", "lucknow");
value.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
ref.child(key).setValue(value);
```